# History not saving

Tags: ruby, irb

Why is my irb history no longer saving?

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that ruby 1.8.7 introduced a bug whereby finalizers are no longer guaranteed to run.

To resolve this, I added the following code snippet to my .irbrc file:

```
require 'irb/ext/save-history'

Kernel.at_exit do
  IRB::HistorySavingAbility.create_finalizer.call(IRB.CurrentContext.instance_variable_get(:@io).send(:binding))
end
```

Comment: Does not work for me.
$ irb -v
irb 0.9.5(05/04/13)
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-12-23 patchlevel 330) [i686-darwin10]

Comment: Thanks a lot! In another answer there were a link to a patch, but that wasn't available any longer. Yes, I have a customer that is still using Ruby 1.8

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this with ruby 2.3.7 as well. It was caused by rvm ruby package not having the correct permissions to update the default .irbrc_history file.  This appears to be a [known bug](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/13907).

An easy work around is to just change the location of this history file in your `~/.irbrc` file.

```
IRB.conf[:HISTORY_FILE] = "#{ENV['HOME']}/.irb_history"
```