# Can I get the Ruby on Rails console to remember my command history, umm, better?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-console

I'm using the console in Ruby on Rails 3.1.1, and I'm finding its command history (up arrow) to be really flaky. I've run the commands `p = Product.by_name 'Acme'` and `p.add_search_term('Snipe')` several times today, across several console sessions.

Yet, when I reload the Ruby on Rails console, only the first one shows in my command history, not the second. Sometimes they are both there in the history after I reload the console. On top of that, I see commands in my history that are from several days ago after pressing up arrow only a few times. Is there some sort of configuration that I need to change or is this a bug?

- Ruby on Rails 3.1.1`
- Ruby 1.9.2p290`
- Ubuntu 11.10`

Comment: Is the problem only with multiple consoles? That would certainly result in unexpected history.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall nope, it's always a dev console that I'm opening in the same window with the same shell script

Comment: Is the problem Rails specific, or do you get the same on a plain irb? Related question for no-Rails: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065923/irb-history-not-working

Comment: Ciro that was a LONG time ago. I don't have this setup anymore and I don't work in Rails anymore. I can't answer your question.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37847822/irb-history-not-working-with-ruby-2-3-0?noredirect=1&lq=1 which discusses how ruby must be complied with `readline`

Answer (score 161, accepted):

From *[How To – Persist Rails or IRB Console Command History After Exit](http://www.wetware.co.nz/2010/09/how-to-persist-rails-or-irb-console-command-history-after-exit/)*.

Create, or edit your `~/.irbrc` file to include:

```
require 'irb/ext/save-history'
IRB.conf[:SAVE_HISTORY] = 200
IRB.conf[:HISTORY_FILE] = "#{ENV['HOME']}/.irb-history"
```

Comment: I wish you'd put the solution (all 3 lines of it) in the body of the answer, in case the link ever goes away.

Comment: Note that RVM has a built-in irbrc that adds history for us: that's why it was working on my local machine but not on the server even without a `~/.irbrc`.

Comment: Also, make sure you install Readline. See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37847822/irb-history-not-working-with-ruby-2-3-0