# rbenv irb history is not saving

Tags: ruby, history, irb, rbenv

I install ruby via [rbenv-installer](https://github.com/fesplugas/rbenv-installer).

When I use irb console, I can use history by pressing up and down on keyboard. And when I exited from console and start it again, I can't use prewious history. When I press up-arrow-button, nothing was happened.

When I used rvm this option was working. How can I switch on it in rbenv?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37847822/irb-history-not-working-with-ruby-2-3-0?noredirect=1&lq=1 which discusses how ruby must be complied with `readline`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I found this way for solving my problem. In file ~/.irbrc write:

```
require 'irb/ext/save-history'
#History configuration
IRB.conf[:SAVE_HISTORY] = 100
IRB.conf[:HISTORY_FILE] = "#{ENV['HOME']}/.irb-save-history"
```

Found in this question: [irb history not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065923/irb-history-not-working)

Comment: Adding just the `IRB.conf[:SAVE_HISTORY] = 10000` line was sufficient to fix things for me.

Comment: If this doesn't work, and you are on OS X, you may need to update your Readline library. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37847822/irb-history-not-working-with-ruby-2-3-0

Comment: I had the same issue on OS X that @EvanPon described. I had to update my Readline library and reinstall Ruby via rbenv. See the post he linked for details.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, in Ubuntu 14.04.  I know that `~/.rbrc` is being processed because I put a `puts` at the top.  But it just doesn't make any difference.  I have Readline installed - at least, I can do `Readline` in the console.

Answer (score 12):

Create ~/.irbrc if it does not exist, and add the following line to it:

```
IRB.conf[:SAVE_HISTORY] = 1000
```

Comment: Sufficient for me (ruby 2.2). History gets saved automatically to `~/.irb_history`