# Is there a way to see a print out of irb history?

Tags: git, irb

I want to see what I wrote in irb. My terminal is past the scroll point to view it. 
Is there a git command to view irb input?

Answer (score 1):

It should be [`irb history`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/irb/rdoc/IRB/History.html).

Make sure your git bash homedir `~` has a `~/.irbrc` file with:

```
require 'irb/ext/save-history'
#History configuration
IRB.conf[:SAVE_HISTORY] = 100
IRB.conf[:HISTORY_FILE] = "#{ENV['HOME']}/.irb-save-history"
```

Then you should be able to read the history in `~/.irb-save-history`.
See "[`rbenv irb history` is not saving](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11137143/6309)"