# irb history saving but not loading

Tags: ruby, readline, irb

I use the following `.irbrc` with irb under ruby 2.3.5 on FreeBSD:

```
require 'irb/completion'
require 'irb/ext/save-history'
IRB.conf[:SAVE_HISTORY] = 10000
IRB.conf[:AUTO_INDENT]  = true
IRB.conf[:USE_READLINE] = true
IRB.conf[:HISTORY_FILE] = "/home/ebot/.irb_history"
```

When I exit irb, the history gets saved to `/home/ebot/.irb_history` as expected. However, when I start another irb session, the `Readline::History` list is empty and pressing the `<up>` key has no effect.

I put the following code into my `.irbrc`:

```
  if File.exist?(IRB.conf[:HISTORY_FILE]) then
    prev = ''
    File.open(IRB.conf[:HISTORY_FILE]).each do |line|
      line.chomp!
      if line.length > 0 then
        if line != prev then
          puts "pushing hist <#{line}>"
          Readline::HISTORY.push(line)
          prev = line
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

When I execute irb with this, I see several lines of the above output, but still, history is empty:

```
% irb
irb(main):001:0> 1+1
=> 2
irb(main):002:0> 3+3
=> 6
irb(main):003:0> ^D

% cat .irb_history 
1+1
3+3

% irb
pushing hist <1+1>
pushing hist <3+3>
irb(main):001:0> Readline::HISTORY.to_a
=> ["Readline::HISTORY.to_a"]
```

So, irb seems to reset/empty this list after executing `.irbrc`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Use [`pry`](http://pryrepl.org/) instead of IRB, since it is much better in general and supports everything you might need, including history, out of the box.

Comment: Great, I've got the same problem with pry as well :( The only difference is, that `.pry_history` contains all commands ever entered. But `<up>` still has no effect. Looks like an readline issue?

Comment: Try `Ctrl`+`R` and start typing the command that is presented in the history. Does it appear in the prompt line?

Comment: Nope. Seems to be an issue with ruby+readline.

Comment: Ok, my fault. I recompiled ruby. In the options menu I had libedit enabled instead of readline. I changed this, rebuilt, and now it works.

Comment: Cool then. My advice would be to still be using `pry`, though :)

Comment: See also [IRB history not working with Ruby 2.3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37847822/irb-history-not-working-with-ruby-2-3-0).

Answer (score 3):

On FreeBSD, ruby needs to be compiled with readline support, not libedit.

Comment: This answer is also valid for Ruby that came with macOS. Installing any other Ruby (from Homebrew, or any Ruby version manager) solves this issue.